# Nested forEach in Mocha selenium web testing failing

Tags: node.js, asynchronous, mocha.js, describe

I'm writing a test script which SHOULD do the following (this is an example but the logic and structure is the same).

- for each item in arr1, call the function arr_func_1.
- inside arr_func_1, log the current item, and then for each item in arr2, call the function arr_func_2.
- inside arr_func_2, log the current item.

The calls are wrapped in its() because if one of the elements in the array fails, then it needs to gracefully fail and continue onto the next element in the array.

The expected outcome for this should be:

1
10
20
30
2
10
20
30
3
10
20
30

Instead, I'm receiving
1
2
3

This leads me to believe that the initial function is being called asynchronously.

```
var arr1 = [1,2,3]
var arr2 = [10,20,30]

function arr_func_1(item){
    console.log(item);

    arr2.forEach(function(item){
        it('should loop through arr2, function(){
            arr_func_2(item);
        })
    });
}

function arr_func_2(item){
    console.log(item);
}

describe('test case', function(){
    arr1.forEach(function(item){
         it('should loop through array 1', function(){   
              arr_func_1(item);
         })
    }
})
```

Answer (score 0):

Tests should be defined before they run. `should loop through arr2` tests are defined when `should loop through array 1` is running, so they are ignored during test run.

Apart from the loops, this is similar to:

```
describe('test case', function(){
     it('should loop through array 1', function(){   
         it('should loop through arr2, function(){})
     })
})
```

`it` block shouldn't be defined inside another `it`.

It possibly needs to be:

```
describe('test case', function(){
  for (const item1 of arr1) {
    it('should loop through array 1', function(){...});

    for (const item2 of arr2) {
      it('should loop through array 2', function(){...});
    }
  }
});
```

Comment: I see. How would I go about achieving what is needed?

Comment: What exactly do you need? The code doesn't explain what these arrays are for.

Comment: We have modals in our system. Each modal contains tabs, and each tab can contain subtabs. So what I want to do is, for each tab, test the subtabs within it.

Comment: Not at my work computer at the moment. Shall try it as soon as and get back to you. Thank you for your input!